# Customizing more in UITabBarController - "configure"

Tags: iphone, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, uinavigationbar

How to modify the UINavigationBarTintColor for "Configure" in "more" in UITabBarController?

I have 10 UINavigationController within a UITabBarController (everything using Interface builder. )

I can easily set the tint color of all UINavigationController's UINavigationBar using Interface builder.

Similarly I also found that we can modify the ***More***'s Tint color as follows.

```
tBarDashboard.moreNavigationController.navigationBar.tintColor=
[UIColor colorWithRed:30/255.0 green:103/255.0 blue:7/255.0 alpha:1.0];
// here tbarDashboard is my UITabBarController.
```

But TabBarController default allows to configure the arrangement of navigation controllers if we have too many navigation controllers in tabbarcontroller.

My question is "how to modify the tint color of *Configure* screen?".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

oops ! I googled & I found something. I looking towards study it.

http://sugartin.info/2012/01/23/uitabbarcontroller-more-configure-customization/

Yo ! I got it.

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)controller willBeginCustomizingViewControllers:(NSArray *)viewControllers {
    UIView *editView = [controller.view.subviews objectAtIndex:1];
    UINavigationBar *modalNavBar = [editView.subviews objectAtIndex:0];
    modalNavBar.tintColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed! Thanks.